A movie about a woman travelling to an alien planet
Around ten years ago, I watched this movie on my local TV. It's in English and subbed in my language. It's probably sci-fi or documentary. Here is part of the plot I remember:  
This woman has a team of scientists, and they're trying to go to another planet. While researching their stuff, they use math as a universal language (you know, calculations and things like that). Then they build a sphere(?) spacecraft to go to the alien planet. The alien planet has many glowing things. The alien there is able to do shape shifting. It changes to the woman's father, and he talks to her. 

This could be the movie "Contact". It stars Jodie Foster. She and her team do use math as the universal language.  They do build a sphere, which sort of teleports her for an instant to another planet.  While travelling, there are many images of glowing stars, galaxies, nebulae, and other astronomical objects.  One of the aliens appears as her father (not her husband), in the form of actor David Morse.  Here is the trailer:



Here is a space-travel scene:



And her father appears around 5:50 in this clip:



